# Docker, database copied to a volume has 0kb size

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I created docker image using following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RPDemo.dll"]
```

The project's database is located in this location `./database/db_demo.db`

Docker image build without issue:

```
docker build -t rpdemo-docker:1.0.0 .
```

I would like to persist database outside of the container. I specified volume mounting with this command:

```
docker run --name rpdemo-container -v /mnt/cache/dev/database:/app/database -p 8383:80 rpdemo-docker:1.0.0
```

It seems that folder inside container is mounted to external folder. The database is copied, but it has 0kb size.

Without -v flag, application is running and database resides inside container and it is usable. Database and other files needs to be persisted to external folder.

UPDATE: I created container again with -v flag. /database folder was mounted to external folder /mnt/cache/dev/database, but /database folder inside container was empty. One of the app pages pulls data from database. Once I clicked on this page, db file was created with 0kb length. This is were connection string expects database to be located. It seems that -v /mnt/cache/dev/database:/app/database overwrites folders content.

Comment: The database is created by your application or it already exist and the build copy the file inside your image?

Comment: If you mount an empty host directory over the `/app/database` container directory that will in fact hide the content in the image.  The easiest way to work around this is to use a relational database in a separate container.

Comment: @jmaitrehenry database already exists. It is located inside project in .\database folder with property set to always copy to output folder.

Comment: @David Maze connection string specifies /database folder as place where db file should be located. Db file is a sqlite and there is no need for separate container. I could use MySql container, but this would be overkill..

Answer (score 0):

As David say in a comment, when you mount a volume, it replace the current directory with the volume.

If your volume is new, it will be an empty directory.

Actually, you add the database in the image, but when you start the container, you replace the database directory with a new one, and your application may create the database file if it doesn't exists. It's why you found an empty sqlite database.

If you want to have your database inside your volume, you have 2 choices:
- Copy manually it in your volume
- Have an init script that copy the database from somewhere into your database directory if it doesn't exists

For the second choice, you may do it in the entrypoint script and you may have a directory with a different name for your database like `/app/init-database` and the script will check if `/app/database/db_demo.db` exists, if not, do `cp /app/init-database/db_demo.db /app/database/db_demo.db`

Comment: I like the script idea, but Dockerfile can have only one Enttrypoint if I'm not mistaken. So there is an issue, how to start the script right after container is created and folders are mounted?

Comment: You can create a script that contains the current entrypoint and your script

Comment: It works! This is a great idea. In fact I did not notice that other containers take the same approach. Thank you both for your help.